# ssd1306 (30 pin) oled display eagle library

Tags: eaglecad, display, oled

I am designing an electronic project in Eagle PCB software. The project having a 30Pin SSD1306 Oled Display. I searched in the internet for the eagle library and i cloud not find a matching one. The oled is bought from aliexpress: [https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/32706685992.html][1]

Does anyone know the library for this exact display?

Comment: Well, when I click the link it says "error 404" (page not found or something)...

Comment: Just design your own part! It would only take a few minutes with the Pulsonix software I use.

Answer (score -1):

Is this the part?

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2625802.pdf

"SSD1306 built-in controller"

And you need a connector to receiver the ribbon cable?

Comment: Yes, the part you shared is matching wit mine! i would like to solder it on pcb.

Comment: I believe you need a connector like this  https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/399?k=flex+cable+connector&k=&pkeyword=flex+cable+connector&sv=0&pv88=20&sf=1&FV=ffe0018f&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25 unless you are planning to remove the flex cable and mate the display to the board via some other means.